# Why can't you declare constant function literals in dart?

Tags: dart, constants

The question came into my mind when I've declared a final callback in a class, and the constructor can be declared as const, and trying to make a constant value of a function like so:

```dart
class MyClass {
  final void Function() callback;

  const MyClass(this.callback);
}


void example1() {
  const foo = MyClass(() {});
}
```

This gives the error:

[image]

Why can I delcare a constant constructor in the first place? What would make an object of MyClass compile-time constant if no function value can be constant?

A simpler example:

```dart
typedef MyVoidCallback = void Function();

void example2() {
  const MyVoidCallback bar = () {};
}
```

This gives the error:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: There was a [proposal to add constant function literals to dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048), but they have not  implemented the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `() {}` is not a constant value, it is rather creating a new instance every time. All functions in dart inherit `Function` class which doesn't have `const` constructor.

However, since functions are top-level members in dart, you can pass them by name (like a variable). So if you define your function outside of any class such that it is a global function, you can pass it as a parameter value in a const constructor.

> UPDATE from `@randal-schwartz` comment: Static functions inside a class can also be passed into these const constructors as parameters.

Below code should work:

```dart
class MyClass {
  final void Function() callback;

  const MyClass(this.callback);
}


void example1() {
  const foo = MyClass(doWork);
}

void doWork() {
  // TODO: do work
}
```

Comment: This actually makes so much sense! Thank you for your detailed answer, exactly what I needed. And the code is working fine 

Comment: You can also define namespaced const functions by using static methods in classes.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yeah, that's true. Forgot to mention it in the answer. Updated it. Thanks.